# PhP script not working on Chrome exntension

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to make a basic chrome extension. For now, it should just dump the content of HTML page back on the popup screen. Since port 80 is used by another process, I am running XAMPP server on port 8080. Below are codes

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version" : 2,
"name" : "Demo",
"description" : "Demo description",
"browser_action": {
        "default_title":"Hello",
        "default_popup":"pop.html"
},
"version": "1",
"permissions": [
    "http://localhost/*"
]
}
```

pop.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Enter your details:</h3>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/db1/script.php" method="POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
    <input type = "text" name="email" placeholder="Your email"><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Go" name = "submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

script.php

```
<pre><?php
     var_dump($_POST);
?>
</pre>
```

Here, Php script fails to run within the extension.
However, the pop.html page works perfectly fine but when I try to run it as a chrome extension, it doesn't. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `htmlentities` for SQL injection? That's not what it's for.

Comment: Ohh I have been trying something else. I forgot to edit it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Submitting a form replaces the page with the server response so your extension popup document is replaced by a normal nonprivileged html page, which no longer has access to Chrome API. The proper method is to use XHR/fetch, and you can find tons of examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your response.Here Php script is not working, so the page is not replaced by server response, it just doesn't do anything. Any workaround for the problem?

Comment: Rightclick the popup, click Inspect, devtools will appear, check the console for errors, etc. It's possible Chrome no longer allows posting of forms inside extension popups for the reason I described above.

Comment: @wOxxOm It doesn't show any error. So there isn't any way to workaround this script?

Comment: Like I said, you need to use XHR/fetch to get the data in js, there are lots of examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes but for that I will need php script on server too right?

Comment: You can use whatever you like on your server, it's not essential.